# Finding SCC using DFS algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Where:

SCC - strongly connected components
DFS - depth first search

This is the graph I was trying to "solve" this way is:

[image]

So I'm starting from the A vertex and go straight to G, setting proccessing times all the way - A = <1, 0> and G = <7, 0>.

Then I go back, G = <7, 8>, then to H = <6, 9>, I = <5, 10>, E = <4, 11>...is this correct? And what's next? I can go to C = <3, 0>, or to F which was not visited yet...I guess I should do:

F = <12, 0>, D = <13, 0>, D = <13, 14>, F = <12, 15>, E = <4, 16>, C = <3, 17>, B = <2, 18>, A = <1, 19>

Is this correct?

Then I reverse the edges (arrows)...How to get SCC now?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not so clear. Yes, in the first step of computing strongly connected component you need to do a DFS on the graph. It seems by $<a,b>$ you denoted $<\mathsf{discovery\_time, finishing\_time}>$ of each vertex in DFS. I think your concept of DFS is not clear. In your graph a valid DFS may proceeded in this order: $A$, $B$, $C$, $E$, $I$, $H$, $G$, $H$, $I$, $E$, $F$, $E$, $C$, $B$, $D$, $B$, $A$. This DFS yields the following $\mathsf{discovery\_time}$ and $\mathsf{finishing\_time}$ pairs: $A=<1, 18>$, $B=<2, 17>$, $C =<3, 14>$, $D = <15, 16>$, $E = <4, 13>$, $F = <11, 12>$, $G = <7, 8>$, $H = <6, 9>$, $I = <5, 10>$.

In the second step you need to reverse the edges of the graph and do another DFS. But in this DFS you need to consider the vertices in decreasing order of $\mathsf{finishing\_time}$s computed during the first DFS. Each DFS tree, in this step, represents a separate SCC---that is all vertices in a particular DFS tree belongs to the same SCC. For example, vertex $A$ has the greatest $\mathsf{finishing\_time}$. If we do a DFS from $A$ with edges reversed, we will get $A, D,$ and $B$ in the DFS tree. And indeed $A, D,$ and $B$ belong to the same SCC. You can find the other SCC yourself.

See Wikipedia or Cormen's *Introduction to Algorithms*' chapter *Elementary Graph Algorithms* for detailed discussion both on DFS and finding strongly connected components.